# How to develop an android application using a Wifi connection

Tags: android, wifi

I want to develop a mobile application (android OS), and I want to know how could I use a WIFI connection to connect 2 or more mobiles ..?, which protocols, which API's..?

Any help please..

Answer (score 0, accepted):

In order to communicate, they first have to discover each other in the network. [Link](http://developer.android.com/training/connect-devices-wirelessly/nsd.html) will help you do discover.

If you already know the IP addresses of each other, then the problem is much simpler. RPC call or HTTP call or use Sockets. There is [this](https://github.com/NanoHttpd/nanohttpd) server which can take http calls on the android application. So, both the applications can have servers hosted.

I've just looked up this [link](http://developer.android.com/training/connect-devices-wirelessly/nsd-wifi-direct.html).